# Azure ServiceBus TopicClient SendAsync implementation in own wrapper

Tags: async-await, idisposable, azureservicebus

what is the proper implementation of SendAsync method of Azure ServiceBus TopicClient?

In the second implementation, will the BrokeredMessage actually be disposed before the SendAsync happens?

```
    public async Task SendAsync<TMessage>(TMessage message, IDictionary<string, object> properties = null)
    {
        using (var bm = MessagingHelper.CreateBrokeredMessage(message, properties))
        {
            await this._topicClient.Value.SendAsync(bm);
        }
    }


    public Task SendAsync<TMessage>(TMessage message, IDictionary<string, object> properties = null)
    {
        using (var bm = MessagingHelper.CreateBrokeredMessage(message, properties))
        {
            return this._topicClient.Value.SendAsync(bm);
        }
    }
```

I would like to get most from await/async pattern.

Comment: Just curious: why you don't want to use await on the same like as SendAsync?

Comment: @cassandrad If you use await it actually means you are "executing" the call, don't you?

Comment: Yes, execution will start immediately and will not block anything before you await it. Is there any issues with that?

Comment: Do you mean in the case of "return this._topicClient.Value.SendAsync(bm);" ?

Comment: No, in case if you will use your first approach: ` await this._topicClient.Value.SendAsync(bm)`. Is there any problems with it?

Comment: No it is actually not, maybe I just don't understand the difference between both. I thought if you return task then the execution is deferred to later, once you actually call await on whole "chain", if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question: the second approach could cause issues with disposed objects, you have to wait ending of `SendAsync` execution before you can release resources.

Detailed explanation.

If you call `await`, execution of a method will be stopped at the same moment and will not continue till awaitable method is not returned. Brokered message will be stored in a local hidden variable and will not be disposed.

If you don't call `await`, execution will continue and all resources of brokered message will be freed before they are actually consumed (as `using` is calling `Dispose` on object at the end) or in the process of consumption. This definetely will lead to exceptions inside `SendAsync`. At this point, execution of `SendAsync` **is actually started**.

What `await` does is “pausing” any current thread and waits for completion of task and it's result. And that's what you actually need. Purpose of `async-await` is to allow execution of some task concurrently with something else, it provides ability to wait for a result of concurrent operation when it is really necessary and further execution isn't possible without it.

First approach is good if every method to the top is an async method too. I mean, if caller of your SendAsync is async Task, and caller of that caller and so on to the top calling method.

Also, consider exceptions that could raise, they are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions). As you can see, there are so-called transient errors. This is a kind of errors that retry can possibly fix. In your code, there is no such exception handling. Example of retry pattern could be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589788.aspx), but mentioned article on exceptions can suggest better solutions and it is a topic of another question. I would also add some logging system to at least be aware of any non transient exceptions.

Comment: That's what I thought. I just needed to double check it. So, to wrap it up: the 1st approach is the best approach as while "awaiting" the "SendAsync" the other threads can do their job. Correct?

Comment: In general — yes. Added more details on possible exceptions that could be important.